# Android:NetworkOnMainThreadException error inside AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, exception, android-asynctask, networkonmainthread

okay so i created a inner class which extends AsycTask in order for my code to run outwith the UI thread. However i'm getting this error so i assume this means some part of my onPostExecute needs to be done in doInBackground however i cant figure out exactly what this is

```
public class asyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(PetrolPriceActivity.this);

        @Override
           protected void onPreExecute() {
          dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
          dialog.setProgress(0);
          dialog.setMax(100);
          dialog.setMessage("loading...");
          dialog.show();
           }

         @Override
           protected String doInBackground(String...parmans){
                {

                    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){


                        publishProgress(1);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }


                    String urlString = petrolPriceURL;
                    String result = "";
                    InputStream anInStream = null;
                    int response = -1;
                    URL url = null;

                    try {
                        url = new URL(urlString);
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        return null;
                    }
                    URLConnection conn = null;
                    try {
                        conn = url.openConnection();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        return null;
                    }

                    // Check that the connection can be opened
                    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
                        try {
                            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            return null;
                        }
                    try
                    {
                        // Open connection
                        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        httpConn.connect();
                        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                        // Check that connection is OK
                        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                        {
                            // Connection is OK so open a reader 
                            anInStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
                            InputStreamReader in= new InputStreamReader(anInStream);
                            BufferedReader bin= new BufferedReader(in);

                            // Read in the data from the RSS stream
                            String line = new String();
                            while (( (line = bin.readLine())) != null)
                            {
                                result = result + "\n" + line;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                            try {
                                throw new IOException("Error connecting");
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }

            return result;

                }
           }
           @Override

           protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...progress){

               dialog.incrementProgressBy(progress[0]);
           }

           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
               // Get the data from the RSS stream as a string

               errorText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.error);
               response = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);

               try
                {
                    // Get the data from the RSS stream as a string
                    result =  doInBackground(petrolPriceURL);
                    response.setText(result);
                    Log.v(TAG, "index=" + result);
                }
                catch(Exception ae)
                {
                    // Handle error
                    errorText.setText("Error");
                    // Add error info to log for diagnostics
                    errorText.setText(ae.toString());
                } 
                if(dialog.getProgress() == dialog.getMax())
                dialog.dismiss();

           }
        }
```

if someone could point out my error as well as show an example of where the code is suppose to go in my doInBackground that would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**problem:**

```
result =  doInBackground(petrolPriceURL);
```

you are implicitly calling the `doInbackground` method in the `onPostExecute` which will actually run in your UI thread instead on a different thread thus resulting to `Android:NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Also it is unnecessary to call `doInBackground` that it is already executed before `onPostExecute` when you execute your `Asynctask`. Just directly use the `result` parameter of the `onPostExecute`.

**sample:**

```
@Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           // Get the data from the RSS stream as a string

           errorText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.error);
           response = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);

            response.setText(result);

            if(dialog.getProgress() == dialog.getMax())
            dialog.dismiss();

       }
```

Comment: great thanks im new to AsycTask but i should have realised this error. That has worked thank you very much for the code example

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the error is related to this part of your code:

```
try
 {
 // Get the data from the RSS stream as a string
 result =  doInBackground(petrolPriceURL);
 response.setText(result);
 Log.v(TAG, "index=" + result);
 }
```

doInBackgound is called automatically when you call asynctask.execute.  To start your task correctly you should (1) create a new instance of your task; (2) pass the string params you need to use in doInBackground in the execute method; (3) use them; (4) return the result to onPostExecute.

For Example:

```
 //in your activity or fragment
 MyTask postTask = new MyTask();
 postTask.execute(value1, value2, value3);

 //in your async task
 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... params){

      //extract values
      String value1 = params[0];
      String value2 = params[1];
      String value3 = params[2];

      // do some work and return result
      return value1 + value2;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result){

      //use the result you returned from you doInBackground method
 }
```

You should try to do all of your "work" in the doInBackground method. Reutrn the result you want to use on the main/UI thread. This will automaticlly be passed as an argument to the onPostExecute method (which runs on the main/UI thread).

Comment: great answer however i had actually returned the value it was a silly mistake in which i was accessing the doInBackground method again in the onPostExecute which was completely useless as this is called when i execute asyncTask anyways. I see my error but thank you very much for the answer